# How to merge multiple dimension array cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I just using function query() of cakePhp. The query will return array something like :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-05',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '11'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '150.000'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-05',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '10'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '250.000'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-06',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '10'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '250.000'
        )
    )
)
```

Now, I want to check if array have the same `cate.date` will merge array (in this case is elements 0,1 of my array). Output something like :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-05',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            (int) 0 => array (
                'rel_data_category' => '11',
                'price' => '150.000'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'rel_data_category' => '10',
                'price' => '250.000'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-06',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            (int) 0 => array (
                'rel_data_category' => '10'
                'price' => '250.000'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Please help!

Comment: `cate_total` ? from where this index coming suddenly in your desired output? it's not in your input. Also desired output have some misplace quote check and ractify

Comment: Yep, I will edit my post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to loop through the results and build a new array with the data in the form you want. You can use the [CakePHP `Hash::extract()` method](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::extract) to map the dates to indexes so that you can combine the data for the dates.

For example:-

```
// Get out all the dates available and then flip the array so that we have a map of dates to indexes
$dates = Hash::extract($results, '{n}.cate.date');
$datesMap = array_flip($dates);
// Define an empty array that we will store the new merged data in
$data = [];
// Loop through the query results and write to the $data array using the map of dates
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $key = $datesMap[$result['cate']['date']];
    $data[$key]['cate'] = $result['cate'];
    $data[$key]['cate_detail'][] = [
        'rel_data_category' => $result['cate_detail']['rel_data_category'],
        'price' => $result['cate_item']['price']
    ];
}
```

Comment: In addition, if my array have `item.code` and I want to check `if (item.code && cate.date) has the same value`. Is there way I can check it once @drmonkeyninja

Comment: @longhoangvan I'm not sure how you want this to look, but you should be able to develop my example code above using some if statements perhaps to deal with your situation.